# Touch screen support Asus EP121

Tags: hardware, asus, compatibility, touchscreen

Has anyone installed 12.04 on the Asus EP121, and if so, what works?
Of all things, the touch screen would be the most important. Has anyone had any luck with it?

Answer (score 3):

I installed 12.04 on my Asus EP121 a couple of weeks ago and everything works out of the box with one exception. The stylus works flawlessly, but touching the screen with your finger results in a 'right click' that won't release.

To fix that grab the [newest egalax driver](http://home.eeti.com.tw/web20/eGalaxTouchDriver/linuxDriver.htm) and install. After that it works beautifully! They've even done some work to the onboard keyboard that automatically pops it up when entering text and hides it when not.