# Ubuntu 14 compatible with Asus Slate EP121 with Touchscreen?

Tags: 14.04, asus, 14.10, touchscreen

I have a (now old) Asus Slate EP121 with a lovely Touchscreen. It seems like several posts here have reported problems with earlier versions of Ubuntu, eg [Touch screen support Asus EP121](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147688/touch-screen-support-asus-ep121) .

I would love to install it if I can be pretty sure the dual Windows 8 and Ubutunu would work, but I'm  hesitant to do all the work without a bit of documentation. Hence this question.

Where should I look to find out this answer, or would one of you know right off the bat?

My goal is to get Dockers running, and 14.10 probably has the best support for that. Thank you!

Comment: Did you test Ubuntu with a live CD or USB flash drive?

Comment: @AibaraIduas, no I have not yet. Is that a sufficient test of hardware compatibility, or are there some gotchas I should know? Thank you! p.s. And are there places to pay for a CD/Dongle to support Ubuntu? I think there used to be but I don't see it now.

Comment: Generally if everything is working (sound, video, etc.) with a live CD then things will probably be fine if you install it on your hard drive. It looks like you can buy CDs from Canonical's store: http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

touch works fine in 15.04.  also got the bluetooth keyboard working out of the box.  still cant rotate the screen though.

fixed the rotation with help here:
 [How can I rotate my display in the most easy way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95812/how-can-i-rotate-my-display-in-the-most-easy-way/616077#616077)

Comment: did you need to follow any special instructions? ty!